# Redirect to another page after radio button selection using framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I can't to redirect to page X to page Y according to user choice after selected a radio button. The console write me:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError:  onClickGo is not defined
```

I declared the pages in my-app.json

```
routes: [
{
    name: 'home',
    path: '/home/',
    url: './pages/home/home.html'
},
{
    name: 'travel',
    path: '/travel/',
    url: './pages/travel/travel.html',
    routes: [

        {
            name: 'travel-ny',
            path: ' ny/',
            url: './pages/travel/ny.html',
        },
        {
            name: 'travel-la',
            path: ' la/',
            url: './pages/travel/la.html',
        },

        {
            name: 'travel-milan',
            path: ' milan/',
            url: './pages/travel/milan.html',
        },

    ]
}
```

The users's choice is taken in travel.html

```
<div data-name="travel" class="page">

<div class="page-content pg-no-padding">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-100 tablet-100 desktop-100">            
    <form class="list" id="travel-form">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label class="item-radio item-content">
                        <input type="radio" name="travel" value="ny" checked="checked"/>
                        <i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
                        <div class="item-inner">
                            <div class="item-title">New York</div>
                        </div>
                    </label>                            
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label class="item-radio item-content">
                        <input type="radio" name="travel" value="la"/>
                        <i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
                        <div class="item-inner">
                            <div class="item-title">Los Angeles</div>
                        </div>
                    </label>                            
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label class="item-radio item-content">
                        <input type="radio" name="travel" value="milan" />
                        <i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
                        <div class="item-inner">
                            <div class="item-title">Milan</div>
                        </div>
                    </label>                            
                </li>

        </form> <!--list--> 

        <div class="block">
            <a class="button button-fill travelChoice" onclick="onClickGo()">Go</a>
        </div>      
    </div><!--col-100-->
</div><!--row-->
```

I put the onClickGo function in travel.js that I included its inside home.html in this way

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/travel.js"></script>
```

The travel.js

```
const onClickGo = () => {
   $$('.travelChoice').on('click', function(){

    //retrieve the value selected
    var selectedValue = $$('.list input:checked').val();
   //go to the page 
   router.navigate('/travel/'+ selectedValue +'/');

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to try this since html load before find your function:

```
 $$('.travelChoice').on('click', function(){

    //retrieve the value selected
    var selectedValue = $$('.list input:checked').val();
   //go to the page 
   router.navigate('/travel/'+ selectedValue +'/');
}
```

Without wrapping it by onClickGo Variable, and remove on click event from button too

```
<a class="button button-fill travelChoice">Go</a>
```

...I think its will be work.....also try to use this to navigate:

```
self.app.router.navigate('/travel/'+ selectedValue, {reloadCurrent: true});
```

By adding reloadCurrent you can open page without fair from cashed html page

Comment: Hi Anees, thank you for your help. I changed it following your solution, but in this way  nothing happens. I also tried  another solution using document.getElementById("travelChoice").addEventListener("click", onClickGo); but both solutions don't work and the console writes nothing

Comment: Welcome @Paul, can you please set alert('555555') in click  $$('.travelChoice').on('click', function(){ alert('555555'); })}; ....etc and check if its show or not

Comment: Important note: if its alert is work try to remove latest backslash in navigate url ..to let url like this: '/travel/'+ selectedValue .... since sub route have not a backslash

Comment: Using the code posted in my question I added the id on the button <a class="button button-fill" id="travelChoice" onclick="onClickGo()">Go</a> and in the file js I changed in $$('#travelChoice') and your line self.app.router.navigate('/travel/'+ selectedValue, {reloadCurrent: true}); it works :D thank you! but it works partially after 4 test the radio button allows to check more than one choice. How it possible? also to load the page i have to click twice

Comment: Nice mate, About radio Its another issue for submit page, usally you can fix it by reloading form page, prevent cache or something else

Comment: Thank you Anees :)

Comment: Welcome Paul :)

Comment: dont forget to pick my answer if it helpful for you :)